# import() in ts is not dynamic? what's the cause?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, node-modules, es6-modules

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), `import()` is a function-like dynamic method. However, I found it not dynamic in my ts project.

Say I have an appleShare.json:

```
{
    price: 123
}
```

And then, there's an index.ts:

```
console.log("update the price to 456...")
// manually modify the json file content making price 456
let currentPrice = await import("./appleShare.json").then(obj=obj.price)
console.log(currentPrice)
```

I ran `index.ts` directly in `vs-code`, the result in console:

```
update the price to 456...
123
```

**I expect 456, but got 123**. From my limited knowledge I guess there are two possible reasons:

1. I have a misunderstanding in `import()` and dynamic importing.
2. My understanding is right but `vs-code` compiled all the code to `js` before executing them. So, I will never get the newly modified price.

I want to ask, what's exactly the cause of the issue, and how to resolve it?

Comment: "dynamic" means you can do `import("someFile" + someVariable)` which you cannot do with a regular import statement. It's static, thus it would not allow you to use varliables `import * from "someFile" + someVariable` is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "dynamic" `import()` has the following different behaviors from the regular `import` which is often referred to as the "static" import.

1. You can construct a module filename in code and can then load that module from the filename you built.  You cannot dynamically build module filenames with the regular `import`.  Filenames for the regular `import` must be statically specified so they are known by anyone who parses the file, but does not run the code in it.  This static declaration enables code analysis for things like tree-shaking and bundling.  The dynamic import cannot be used as effectively with features like that.
2. The `import()` can happen anywhere in your code (not only at the top of your module).  The regular `import` cannot be just anywhere in your code.  In this sense, it is "dynamically" loaded upon demand, not only at the beginning of the module.
3. A dynamic `import()` statement can be used to load an ESM module into a CommonJS module.  The regular `import` statement cannot be used in a CommonJS Module at all.

Modules, even dynamically loaded ones are cached.  Once they are loaded, subsequent `import()` statements using the same filename just load the module from the cache, they do not re-read the file.  That's why your subsequent `import()` is not picking up the modified JSON.

If you want to re-read the file, then don't use `import` - use something like `fs.promises.readFile()` and then parse the JSON.  This will read a fresh copy of the data each time you call it.